# Book where a human ship returns to Earth to find humans are savages and crocodiles have become intelligent

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a science fiction book that may or may not have been published. I work for a printing company so I see a lot of obscure books. I read the book about ten years ago.

The book I'm trying to find is about people who travel to a distant planet to retrieve alien tech, but on the return home their ship is damaged. In cryosleep, they return to Earth 10,000 years later and nothing is left. Humans have become savages and crocodiles have become intelligent.

Comment: Sounds like a ripoff of the Planet of the Apes concept. Don't get me wrong, I love a well-done ripoff.